# How to Access Multiple Classes data in One MainClass?

Tags: iphone, xcode, abstract-class

I am working on one of big project.so that's why my application contains a lot of coding. Interesting thing about this project is that it contains only one mainview and this mainview contains 25 subviews, each subview contains UITableview.so problem for me is that if I declare all these subview and uitableview in mainview along with different function which I need for every subview it create confusion. Now to make it easy I want to create separate class for each subview, but I am not familiar with how to access all these classes in my mainviewviewcontroller. Still if some one not able to understand my problem then please visit this link. http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/05/02/passing-data-between-classes/

Comment: The approach you have shown in the link will only be scalable, if the data to be shared is of very less. For more data you will loose scalability with this solution.

Comment: wait, your problem is passing data between classes OR how you would use your subclass objects from your main class ???

Comment: @i4Apple my problem is that for example for the time being i define the outlet and some funtion which i have for my first subview in my mainclass.but now i want to place all this code in new class with the name firstclass and then access firstclass in my mainclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from your comment that you already have coded something like you have mentioned in your problem, and now, you trying to make your code scalable and making it separate as zoul has suggested.

As zoul has mentioned, There isn't any exact solution to your problem, as your problem is also not exact, or say specific.

Unfortunately, It is not fully possible what you are trying to achieve, as you have mentioned in your comment. But, Let me try to give you some hint that you may find useful when refactoring your code.

1. Decide what data needs to be shared among the different classes.
2. Decide View Controllers for your application. By saying this I mean, number of View Controllers, as your application might need. It also may be possible that you can accomplish the task with less number of view controllers.
3. If size of shared data is considerably large then, I would suggest that you would SQLite or CoreData for that, whichever suits your need.

Specific query is welcome.
Best of luck :)

Additional Note: Try to follow the design pattern provided by Apple, most importantly in the initial phase of SDLC.

Comment: please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349445/how-to-access-the-subclass-features-in-mainclass

Answer (score 1):

First, certainly do split the code into separate controllers or views, otherwise you would enter the world of pain. Second, it's hard to answer your current question here on Stack Overflow, because this is a question about architecture and answering it properly requires a longer discussion about your problem; there is no ready solution.

Generally, in such cases you want to build the individual screens or views as separate controllers with interfaces that allow them to be connected together as needed. (Try hard to design the individual controllers to know as little about the others as possible.) Then you can have one class that will create all the components and connect them together. There are many particular tools that can help with that, especially the `UIViewController` containment API introduced in iOS 5.

Comment: thanx for quick respone.for the time being i need to access the every feature of firstclass in mainclass.

Comment: Your current question is too abstract, I don't think there's a reasonably simple answer. I'd suggest that you think about it some more, come up with a sample scenario with clean code samples and submit a new question.

Comment: Oky i will try to make it clear in a new question.

Comment: please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349445/how-to-access-the-subclass-features-in-mainclass

Answer (score 1):

Going by your problem of using the same code in a new/different class time to time, re-usability is the key.
But to get this correct you must follow the "Loose Coupling and High Cohesion" principle.
Essentially, you need create each sub-view like a component by itself, which performs a specific task and is not aware or dependent on external factors like its parent etc.
Lastly, I feel the main problem you are facing trying to resuse code is because you are using IB for wiring up function to UI events.
I would suggest using target and selector properties for wiring as this will ease resuability and also keep your code discreet and cleaner.

You can read more about coupling and cohesion here [Loose Coupling and High Cohesion](http://www.xyzws.com/scjp/SGS11/5/2)