# How to access the SubClass features in MainClass?

Tags: iphone, xcode, subclass

About this problem my previous question is that.  [How to Access Multiple Classes data in One MainClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346578/how-to-access-multiple-classes-data-in-one-mainclass)   Now to make my problem more clear i provide  source  code here [SourceCode.](http://www.hilbert1862.com/sc/viewtestapp.zip)       As my source Code show i declare all the classes in my mainclass and my coding is in my mainclass.But i want to place all my mainclass code to its related class that i create in my application.For Exp Code related to first Class i want to place all there and Code related to Second Class place in Second Class.Now problem for me is that if i place all code to its related Classes then how we can access these Classes.Any Help will be appriated?

Comment: You should really start with learning the [Objective-C language](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).

Comment: here u made firstView & secondView as UIViewController, and want to use in its tableViewController.. do you want to use firstView & secondView as view controllers.? what kind of code you want to write in these subclasses..?

Comment: @lena Is your codebase so large, that you can't afford rewriting your App from scratch? Think through it. As I might create a new project for this kind of changes.

Comment: then u can add all the related code in their classes, and have to use main class as a mediator have to pass the respective instance of that class/view/table..

Comment: @vishy Now u understand my  problem.please give me any suggestion how to use mainclass as mediator.thanx

Comment: ok, check d answer i made the changes to the existing, download the update from here..

Comment: Please don't link to source code hosted externally as a zip archive, it hurts the site usability and makes the question less useful for other readers. Take the effort to insert a minimal source code example into your question. If that looks hard, you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the tables, views in the main class/controller. Then create all other objects with in that as subclass a table/views and from xib change the class name.

The [sample](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/viewtestapp.zip) one i have made the changes for first view & second view as subclass of UIView.

And the animations which you made in main class, i have made it from the first-class or second-class by passing the required views/objects to perform that function.

Check out the changes i have made.

Comment: if u please give me the email address then i will send u more detail about the problem.thanx

Comment: Your profile d'nt have u r have email address.by the way thanx a lot i try to explain my problem to you .